# Unable to build vim on windows with MinGW

Tags: windows, vim, mingw

I tried building `vim` and `gvim` with `MinGW` according to [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Build_Python-enabled_Vim_on_Windows_with_MinGW) instruction. For convenience I'm posting them here

```
@echo off
REM Run this batch file from any directory to build gvim.exe and vim.exe.
REM But first edit the paths and Python version number.

REM --- Specify Vim /src folder ---
set VIMSRC=C:\Downloads\vim\src
REM --- Add MinGW /bin directory to PATH ---
PATH = C:\MinGW\bin;%PATH%
REM --- Also make sure that PYTHON, PYTHON_VER below are correct. ---

REM get location of this batch file
set WORKDIR=%~dp0
set LOGFILE=%WORKDIR%log.txt

echo Work directory: %WORKDIR%
echo Vim source directory: %VIMSRC%

REM change to Vim /src folder
cd /d %VIMSRC%

REM --- Build GUI version (gvim.exe) ---
echo Building gvim.exe ...
REM The following command will compile with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.3
mingw32-make.exe -f Make_ming.mak PYTHON="C:/Python27" PYTHON_VER=27 DYNAMIC_PYTHON=yes PYTHON3="C:/Python35" PYTHON3_VER=35 DYNAMIC_PYTHON3=yes FEATURES=HUGE GUI=yes gvim.exe > "%LOGFILE%"

REM --- Build console version (vim.exe) ---
echo Building vim.exe ...
REM The following command will compile with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.3
mingw32-make.exe -f Make_ming.mak PYTHON="C:/Python27" PYTHON_VER=27 DYNAMIC_PYTHON=yes PYTHON3="C:/Python35" PYTHON3_VER=35 DYNAMIC_PYTHON3=yes FEATURES=HUGE GUI=no vim.exe >> "%LOGFILE%"

echo Moving files ...
move gvim.exe "%WORKDIR%"
move vim.exe "%WORKDIR%"

echo Cleaning Vim source directory ...
REM NOTE: "mingw32-make.exe -f Make_ming.mak clean" does not finish the job
IF NOT %CD%==%VIMSRC% GOTO THEEND
IF NOT EXIST vim.h GOTO THEEND
IF EXIST pathdef.c DEL pathdef.c
IF EXIST obj\NUL      RMDIR /S /Q obj
IF EXIST obji386\NUL  RMDIR /S /Q obji386
IF EXIST gobj\NUL     RMDIR /S /Q gobj
IF EXIST gobji386\NUL RMDIR /S /Q gobji386
IF EXIST gvim.exe DEL gvim.exe
IF EXIST vim.exe  DEL vim.exe
:THEEND

pause
```

I'm getting the following error during a build process:

```
Building gvim.exe ...
diff.c: In function 'ex_diffpatch':
diff.c:891:12: error: storage size of 'st' isn't known
     stat_T st;
            ^
diff.c:891:12: warning: unused variable 'st' [-Wunused-variable]
mingw32-make.exe: *** [gobjx86-64/diff.o] Error 1
Building vim.exe ...
diff.c: In function 'ex_diffpatch':
diff.c:891:12: error: storage size of 'st' isn't known
     stat_T st;
            ^
diff.c:891:12: warning: unused variable 'st' [-Wunused-variable]
mingw32-make.exe: *** [objx86-64/diff.o] Error 1
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was the problem. I was using a 32 bit `MinGW` instead of the one for 64 bit system. In other words I needed to download `MinGW-w64` from https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php instead of downloading `MinGW` from http://www.mingw.org/.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what this problem is; but if I were you I would follow [the instructions by Antoine Mechelynck](http://users.skynet.be/antoine.mechelynck/vim/), which are very detailed. I've used his guide for building at Unix/Linux guide and they are very good.

You could consider downloading the binary from [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) if you still have problems to build it. There is also a [portable version (from PortableApps)](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/gvim_portable), which doesn't requires privileges to install and even run from USB stick.